# Organization runner not showing in new repositories

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

We have around 50 repositories under our organization and we have setup a runner dedicated for our developement deployment. The runner was available to the repositories which was created before adding the runner, but when we added a new repository, we are unable to see the organization runner in the runner section. You can see the images here:

[image: repo_with_runner]

[image: repo_without_runner]

The repository settings are all the same. Do I have to give access somewhere for it to show up in this new server?

I have checked for answers in the Internet and found none. I also cross checked the permissions given in the repository level and organizational level but all of them are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I haven't included the new repository in the **Runner Group**.

Go to Organisation settings > Actions > Runner groups > *your_runner_server* > Repository access. I have given **"All repositories"** in my case so I can access it from any of my private repositories.

[image: screenshot]